Accesssing fields from a struct[] returns a very large integer
I have a C++ program that creates a two-element array of structs, then outputs the a field from one of the structs based on user input.
When user the inputs 1 to the program, it should print 0 since the a field of the second struct has a value of 0. However, after enabling optimizations and compiling with the win32 release of MSVC, it prints out 281474976710656 (2^48) instead.
Reproduction environment:

Visual Studio 2022 Platform Toolset v143
Release Win32
Optimization (default) (Maximum, Favor Speed) \O2
Language Standard c++14 (default)

The bug disappears if I turn off the optimization, change the release to debug, or switch to GCC or Clang.
#include <iostream>

struct MyData
{
    int64_t a;
    int64_t b;
};

int main()
{
    MyData dataList[2]
    {
        {1000, -1 }, /* change -1 to another number. say 3, the result will be -3 * 2^48 */
        { 0, 0 },
    };

    int i;
    std::cin >> i;
    i = i % 2;

    int64_t c = -dataList[i].a;  /* if we just do : std::cout << -dataList[i].a. the result will be correct...*/
    std::cout << c << std::endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

I believe this may be a compiler bug. Why is it occurring, and how can I avoid it?

Can't reproduce (neither locally nor on godbolt). What compiler version?

@HolyBlackCat reproduced by adding /O2 option: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qEe1cYzME

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp/report

Looks like a bug. Compiling for 64 bit works though so perhaps consider dropping 32 bit support for your program.

What happens if std::int64_t is used instead of mere  int64_t? Try static_assert(std::is_signed_v<int64_t>); with <type_traits> and std::cout<<std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min(); with <limits>. If the minimum value is anything but negative, or assertion fails or std::int64_t has the same fate, sth is wrong with the compiler.

@Red.Wave just tried std::int64_t.  bug still exists.
